# Badminton Correct Score

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to find a way to calculate the chances of one player winning a game on badminton match to a specific score:

a Match of badminton is to the best of 3 games. Each game is won by the player who reaches 21 points first. But has to win by two. In case a 20-20 draw happens, then one player has to get two additional points. But this rule only applies until 30, where one player can win by 30-29. I hope this was clear.

So, I wanted to calculate the chances of a 21-0 score, 21-1, 21-2, etc until the 30-29.

I have done this assuming that the chances of Player A winning one point are the inverse of player B: So, if Pa is Players A chances of winning one point, 1-Pa=Pb chances of Player B winning one point.

But I see this approach as weak. In fact we should have 4 parameters:

Pa= player A chances of winning a point when serving
Qb= player B chances of winning a point when receiving
Pb= player B chances of winning a point when serving
Qa= player A chances of winning a point when receiving.

So, now my problem is that I don't know how to calculate, for each possible scoreline, how many combinations we can get. And thing can get even more complicated when we assume that can happen points in a row or not:

For instance, ABAB is not the same as AABB, although this is 2-2 in terms of scoreline. Because on the ABAB both players lost their serve twice, and on the second example, both won one point on serve and lost one point on serve.

Can you point me on the right direction on how to solve this ?

thank you

Comment: You already indicated that there are awful lot of combinations to consider right of the bat (or racket), and so to make a general formula isn't going to be easy. Yes, I am quite familiar with the sport, and to make things worse, one can score against the serve of the opponent (which, by the way, wasn't the case in the past), and so every point counts, irrespective who serves. I do think that some programmer "nerd" can see a challenge in this assignment.

Comment: Maybe there is a short-cut to solve this ? I thought about recursive formulas with forward looking, but if they work I still don't know how.

Comment: Doing this by hand will be effectively impossible. Simulating a lot of games will be much easier. Alternatively, a Markov Chain model could work well, you would need a big state space (I would set it up with 64 times 64 states, for each possible score combination plus an absorbing "win" state, all with two combinations for the different server). I think the equations would be relatively straight-forward though, and you just need to take a large power of a 64 by 64 sparse matrix, which isn't so big a computational problem. Simulating is definitely going to be a lot easier though!

Comment: I have continued searching for the answer to my question and I think I was able to sort it after reading this article "Score probabilities for serve and
rally competitions" from Ilan Adler and Sheldon M. Ross. I have already computed their formulas and results seem fine..